# How to add props to dynamic component in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I create component dynamically:

```html
<component is="tab"/>
```

How to add props for this component? I try:

```html
<component is="tab" my-props="test" />
```

And I got error in console:

```
[Vue warn]: Attribute "type" is ignored on component <component> because the component is a fragment instance: http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Fragment-Instance
```

P.S. I'm using 1.0.26 version vue.js.

Comment: What does your tab component look like? The problem might not necessarily be related to the prop you are passing.

Comment: The problem might be with the attribute/variables found in your component. Post the codes!

Comment: It is not variable, it is simple text. Without 'my-props' attribute I dont have this warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If test not just "test" text, but some value in your data. Then you need to pass it like so:

```
<component is="tab" :props="test" />
```

And don't forget to add your properties in `props` array inside component. `props: ['props']`.

http://jsbin.com/zekiyeroka/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Here is working example. Adding to the data is optional, but i prefer this way. Because you can operate your data in the much easier way in the future.

P.S. you need to declare your `data` in the component like a `function`, not just `object`

Comment: It is not working example, it is just jquery code which  not relevant for this question.

Comment: @Slava fixed. Check it now

Comment: Yes, I see. Thank you!